# create trigger to update some column after update specific column in same table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table called BrrowedBookBy 
[here is the table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vTsQ.png)

```
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ISBN_B             | char(50)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PIN_M              | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| StartDate          | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| EndDate            | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| BrrowBookCondition | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Late               | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ReNew              | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Fine               | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Fine_Description   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.040 sec)
```

so I want to set trigger on updating the BorrowBookCondition Column

I tried as this but not working in Maria

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER Set_fine
  AFTER Update ON BorrowedBookBy
   FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE Fine SET Fine = 50 and fine_description = “Not Meet The Condition”
      where BrrowBookCondition in (select * from BorrowedBookBy where BrrowBookCondition =0);
```

If I type it as this without any condition it's working just fine

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER Set_fine
  AFTER Update ON BorrowedBookBy
   FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE Fine SET Fine = 50 and fine_description = “Not Meet The Condition”;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused.  Your trigger is referring to *another table* called `Fine`, but you have not mentioned this.

Are you sure you don't want to set this in the same row being updated?

If so:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER Set_fine BEFORE Update ON BorrowedBookBy
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.BrrowBookCondition = 0 THEN
        SET Fine = 50;
        SET fine_description = 'Not Meet The Condition;
    END IF;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: yes this is working before event , but I want it after the insert , it's show this bug "Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger"

Comment: @Rehab . . . Then you missed that this is a BEFORE trigger.